# Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR no values?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

Fellow coders!

I've attempted to create an application in Android Studio where the screen changes color whenever the screen is tilted 45 degrees or more. Problem is nothing happens!

Listener gets registered successfully but the toast I prepared in the onSensorChanged-method never gets called which tells me there are no readings coming in. Is there something I overlooked?

Best regards and thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I fixed the toast as suggested by **Andy** (thank you). Now I can see what readings I get since the app is not working as intended.

**EDIT2:** After being able to watch the readings I got the app to work! The conversion to degrees was indeed working as intended and I was getting constant readings. Had to change that toast to a textview in order to make any sence out of it. **PROBLEM SOLVED**

```
public class RotationVectorActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor rotationVector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rotation_vector_layout);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        rotationVector = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);

        if(rotationVector == null) {
            MainActivity.showToast(this, "Proximity sensor not available.");
            finish();
        } else {
            registerListener();
        }
    }

    public void launchMain(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We got this far?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, event.values);

        //Remap coordinate system
        float[] remappedRotationMatrix = new float[16];
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
                SensorManager.AXIS_X,
                SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
                remappedRotationMatrix);

        //Convert to orientations
        float[] orientations = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedRotationMatrix, orientations);

        //Convert radians to degrees
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            orientations[i] = (float)(Math.toDegrees(orientations[i]));
        }

        if(orientations[2] > 45) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if (orientations[2] < -45) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (Math.abs(orientations[2]) < 10) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterListener();
    }

    public void registerListener() {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, rotationVector, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        MainActivity.showToast(this, "Rotation vector listener registered.");

    }

    public void unregisterListener() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        MainActivity.showToast(this, "Rotation vector listener unregistered.");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Toast.makeText` in `onSensorChanged` - is never `show`n.  Just append `.show()`.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you! I've changed it so it looks the same as in my register/unregister methods bellow, now I can find out what readings I get and why the app is not working as intended.